# Work on feature branch, committed code but never pushed due to test failing.Removed the repository locally, re-cloned the repo

Tags: git, branch

Is the branch gone forever?

Ive gone through the git history locally, both in terminal and through IntelliJ, but I can not see any reference to the branch.

Comment: If you really completely deleted the local repo _and_ you never pushed that branch, then unfortunately the branch is probably gone forever.

Comment: Your branch is gone if you did exactly what you wrote in the question.

Comment: I feared as much, cheers anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you deleted working copy without push, you lost the work. This is the reason, why you should regularly push to feture branches, even if it is not ready or failing.

Comment: Build process prevents code being pushed if linting fails or tests fail

Comment: @thermos12 That is why to use girflow and use feature branches which have no such restriction. Restriction should be on merging the pull request. Not pushing daily work on a remote server is always a risk of loss.